# application role to active directory group mapping in weblogic server admin console

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using fusion middleware 12c for application development. I am trying to implement ADF security in my application over weblogic server. I am defining my application roles which are reflecting on my Entity Manager console, similarly I am using active directory provider for authentication and getting users and groups from there, these are also reflecting on my entity manager console.

When I try to map these groups, I am getting from AD to my application roles. i.e when I click on the 'add' button there, it doesn't show the groups from the AD there... both my provider and my application roles are defined in same realms, so why isn't it showing my groups there?

Comment: Your are trying to add a group from AD to a group internal to weblogic (like Administrators)? What happens when you type in the group name and click Add?

Comment: Hi,I am trying to add a group from AD to an application role I have defined in my zazn-xml so that i can authenticate users who belong to this group in AD to get certain grants.... so,when i click on edit

Comment: continuation from above......I am not getting enterprise groups from my AD amonf the groups it is showing which i may add to this application role...It should ideally show them as is shown in this youtube video from 1:30 mins onward 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNFKdqEfQy4